# My game objects do not bump into each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision

Very weird question, I'm not even sure why or how this happened, but I have 2 game objects that actually collide because I have a event for when that happens (explosion), but the objects do not actually hit eachother anymore. All of a sudden they fail to stop eachother when they hit eachother. I'm sorry if this sounds weird, I almost don't even know how to describe my problem. I'll post code, not sure if that will make any difference, but please, ask me anything that you might be "oh I think this might be why, what's your setting for.." etc. They used to hit eachother but now they just pass through as if they had no matter, BUT they collide because it triggers an explosion. (it doesn't destroy it,  so no, it's not because the game object is destroyed).

AIScript

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AIScript : MonoBehaviour {
private PlayerScript GO;
public Transform target;
public Transform myTransform2;
public GameObject Comp;
public GameObject splosion;
public int maxDistance;
public int rotationSpeed;
public int moveSpeed;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    GO = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<PlayerScript>();

    target = GO.transform;
    maxDistance = 2;
}

void Awake() {
    myTransform2 = transform;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (GO.colorRed) 
    {
        Debug.DrawLine (target.position, myTransform2.position, Color.red);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Debug.DrawLine (target.position, myTransform2.position, Color.blue);
    }

    //handles rotation of AI
    myTransform2.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (myTransform2.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - myTransform2.position), rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Vector3.Distance(target.position, myTransform2.position) > maxDistance && GO.stopAI)
    {
        //Move towards target
        myTransform2.position += myTransform2.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
    }

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.transform.tag == "Player")
    {
        Instantiate (splosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    }
}

}
```

PlayerScript

```
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {

// globals
private AIScript GO;
public string moveL;
public string moveR;
public string moveU;
public string moveD;
//
public float playerSpeed;
//
public bool colorRed;
public bool stopAI;
//
public GameObject splosion;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    GO = GameObject.Find("Computer").GetComponent<AIScript>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    stopAI = false;

    if(Input.GetKey (moveL))
    {
        colorRed = true;
        stopAI = true;
        GO.Comp.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
        SetTransformX((transform.position.x) - playerSpeed);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey (moveR))
    {
        colorRed = true;
        stopAI = true;
        GO.Comp.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
        SetTransformX((transform.position.x) + playerSpeed);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey (moveU))
    {
        colorRed = false;
        stopAI = true;
        GO.Comp.renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
        SetTransformY((transform.position.y) + playerSpeed);
    }
    if(Input.GetKey (moveD))
    {
        colorRed = false;
        stopAI = true;
        GO.Comp.renderer.material.color = Color.clear;
        SetTransformY((transform.position.y) - playerSpeed);
    }

    else
    {
        rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
}

void SetTransformX(float n)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(n, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}

void SetTransformY(float n)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, n, transform.position.z);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you made sure either object doesn't have the is Trigger checkbox set accidentally?

Comment: Did you attach a rigid body to them? What about a mesh collider?

Comment: You've got OnTriggerEnter in one of the scripts, so I'm assuming one of them is a trigger and one isn't. If that isn't causing your issue, then perhaps the two objects are on different layers?

Comment: Yeah I checked the isTrigger so that it reads my collision. I unchecked it, and it works, but now my explosion doesn't happen. Any way around that?

Answer (score 1):

Needed to change OnTriggerEnter to OnCollisionEnter, and then change Collider, with Collision.